# Apiary Blueprint attributes under headers and body are not recognized

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

Final Edit: This works with no semantic errors:

```
+ Request

    + Headers

            Accept: application/json
            Content-Type: application/json
            X-Auth-Client: Your Client Id
            X-Auth-Token: Your Token

    + Body

    + Attributes (ProductPost)


+ Response 200

    + Headers

            Content-Encoding: Entity header is used to compress the media-type.
            Content-Type: application/json
            Date: The date the response was sent.
            Transfer-Encoding: Header specifies the form of encoding used to safely transfer the entity to the user.
            Vary: HTTP response header determines how to match future request headers to decide whether a cached response can be used rather than requesting a fresh one from the origin server. We use Accept Encoding
            X-Rate-Limit-Requests-Left: Header details how many remaining requests your client can make in the current window before being rate-limited. 
            X-Rate-Limit-Requests-Quota: Header shows how many API requests are allowed in the current window for your client 
            X-Rate-Limit-Time-Reset-Ms: Header shows how many milliseconds are remaining in the window. 
            X-Rate-Limit-Time-Window-Ms: Header shows the size of your current rate-limiting window

    + Body

    + Attributes (ProductResponse)
```

Edit: The header section is rendering, but now the Body section is just showing the text " + Attributes (ProductPost)"

```
+ Request

    + Headers

            Accept: application/json
            Content-Type: application/json
            X-Auth-Client: Your Client Id
            X-Auth-Token: Your Token



+ Response 200

    + Headers

            Content-Encoding: Entity header is used to compress the media-type.
            Content-Type: application/json
            Date: The date the response was sent.
            Transfer-Encoding: Header specifies the form of encoding used to safely transfer the entity to the user.
            Vary: HTTP response header determines how to match future request headers to decide whether a cached response can be used rather than requesting a fresh one from the origin server. We use Accept Encoding
            X-Rate-Limit-Requests-Left: Header details how many remaining requests your client can make in the current window before being rate-limited. 
            X-Rate-Limit-Requests-Quota: Header shows how many API requests are allowed in the current window for your client 
            X-Rate-Limit-Time-Reset-Ms: Header shows how many milliseconds are remaining in the window. 
            X-Rate-Limit-Time-Window-Ms: Header shows the size of your current rate-limiting window


    + Body

            + Attributes (ProductCollectionResponse)
```

I am trying to define the Request Body and after reading this: 
https://help.apiary.io/api_101/apib-authentication/ &
https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#def-headers-section

It seemed like I could split them into sections. But the Attributes section is not being recognized. This is a /GET request.

Any ideas why?

```
+ Request (application/json)

    + Headers

        + Attributes (RequestHeaders) 

    + Body

        + Attributes (ProductPost)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers section can't contain Attributes, you need to define them explicitly. Just replace:

```
    + Attributes (RequestHeaders)
```

with definition of `RequestHeaders`.

Also try to align Body and Attributes at the same column:

```
+ Body
+ Attributes (ProductPost)
```

Comment: I did that, but now the Body is not rendering. I added the update in the question above

Comment: @T.J. remove empty line after Body and align them at the same column

Comment: @T.J. don't align at the same column, just remove empty line

Comment: response shouldn't contain Headers

Comment: Alex a 200 response does have headers for our api and includes rate limit information that is needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170305/discussion-between-alex-and-t-j).